# Fatal error: Call to a member function setText() on a non-object in

Tags: magento-1.9

Here's the code that throwing that issue:

```
public function indexAction()

{

    $this->loadLayout();



    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text', 'inner-wrap-start')->setText('<div id="searchanise-settings-wrapper">'));

    $this->_addContent(

        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/template')

            ->setTemplate('searchanise/dashboard.phtml'));



    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text', 'inner-wrap-end')->setText('</div>'));



    $this->renderLayout();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can only happen if `createBlock()` returns false here:

```
    try {
        $block = $this->_getBlockInstance($type, $attributes);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        return false;
    }
```

i.e. `_getBlockInstance()` throws an exception. You can check `var/log/exception.log` to see what went wrong, but it's most likely "Invalid block type: core/text". This should not happen, please make sure that the parameter `'core/text'` does not contain invalid characters in your code, and that `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text.php` is present and readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
($this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text', 'inner-wrap-start')->setText('<div id="searchanise-settings-wrapper">')
```

**code is working perfectly at backend system.**

please check  `Mage_Core_Block_Text` class exit or  not  at **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text.php**